# How to ignore corrupted xml row with parse_xml in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parsexml

Function parse_xml fails with message **Error parsing XML: not an XML element, pos 1**, this is due to one invalid xml entry, is there anyway to ignore the invalid one and proceed.

Here is a background
I get's a xml data into snowflake table through a rest service which stores as an varchar, further picks this data, parses into xml and does filtering/processing. Function parse_xml working well in our case but it gave's up if any one entry invalid.

Here is an example query below, I am looking to ignore "red" and return "green" instead of throwing error.

```
SELECT parse_xml(XML)
FROM
  (SELECT ('<color>green</color>') XML
   UNION SELECT ('red') XML);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the XML for validity with `check_xml()`:

```sql
SELECT parse_xml(XML)
FROM
  (SELECT ('<color>green</color>') XML
   UNION SELECT ('red') XML)
WHERE check_xml(XML) is NULL ;
```

This returns `<color>green</color>`, as desired.